# Clean URL: Url redirecting 302 instead of showing it a clean URL

Tags: .htaccess, apache, httpd.conf, clean-urls

I am trying to create clean URL by editing the `httpd.conf` file but instead of getting clean URLs, my page is getting redirected to the dirty URL. Here is the condition that I am writing.

```
RewriteRule ^/show/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+) http://www.example.com/show.php?id=$1&img=$2 [L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Should have been

```
RewriteRule ^/show/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+) /show.php?id=$1&img=$2 [L]
```